# HTTP Status Code 504 happens only when requests are sent from one specific server

Tags: web-services, http, asp.net-web-api

I have a program that I install on my clients' server which sends a couple of HTTP requests to a web service. This has always worked fine, but for one client the requests always get a 504 - Gateway Timeout Error. When I send the same requests from my own computer, I always get a quick 200 OK response.

My initial thought was that it must be some kind of firewall issue, however requests do occasionally get a 200 OK response.

Any ideas on what may cause this and what I can do about it?

Comment: Have you investigated all the headers properly? And do you test exactly the same request from your computer and other server?

Comment: Yes, I copied the raw headers and sent the exact same request. Also, I have set up this program for a number of clients and they are stilling working fine

Comment: What about server logs?

Comment: Do you mean the IIS web server logs where my API resides, or logs from the client's server (and which logs) ?

Comment: Rather the server that times out. Have you investigated all the logs?

Comment: which logs? I have only looked through different logs in event viewer, but they don't show any errors (or warnings)